# is there a way to convert the matrix of result into a single column with factor

Tags: r, neural-network

I was running ANN using the [neuralnet](/questions/tagged/neuralnet) package. the classify independent variable is converted into factor. the compute function return a 3 by number of row with 1 in the result factor, 1 at column 1 for class 1, 1 at column 2 for class 2 and 1 at column 3 for class 3. How can i convert this data into a single column with 1, 2 and 3 as the result?
[image: this is the data frame]

```
#prediction 
pred.wine.nn.5.5 <- neuralnet::compute(wine.nn.5.5, wine.test[,2:14])
pred.wine.nn.5.5 <- round(pred.wine.nn.5.5$net.result, digits = 0)
```

this result in
[image: the rounded net result where one denote the class and the class is in the column]

I can't find a way to convert this matrix result into a one column result with factor like the class column in the dataframe.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understood your structure correctly, but could you not just use `t(x) ` or convert it to a vector (`as.vector`)? If that's not the case could you add an example data set with the structure to your question?

Comment: hi i fix the question to make it easier to understand. any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

As one solution you can multiply the binary matrix with a vector:

```r
as.matrix(pred.wine.nn.5.5) %*% c(1,2,3)
```